# How to use switch statement in c

Tags: c, switch-statement, statements

How can I use `switch` statement in the following lines, as I don't want to make the `if` statement bulky.

```c
if(uword1 == (65|69|73|76|78|79|82|83|84|85)) {
    total1++;
    printf("%i", total1);
}
```

Comment: As written, it won't do what you want.  The 10 numbers are all or'd together (the result is 95 = 0x5F) and the result is compared to `uword1`.  You'll write `switch (uword1) { case 65: … case 85: total1++; printf("%i", total1); break; default: …appropriate action — maybe no action; break; }`.

Comment: @justANewbie It rather depends on your definition of "works". :)

Comment: Careful with `|`. It is the bitwise **OR**. Probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: "i dont want to make the if statement bulky" is to approach this the wrong way. What you should strive for is not make the generated machine code bulky. In this case you can make an execution speed optimization with a look-up table.

Answer (score 3):

```
  switch (uword1) {
    case 65:
    case 69:
    case 73:
    case 76:
    case 78:
    case 79:
    case 82:
    case 83:
    case 84:
    case 85:
        total1++;
        printf("%i", total1);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether to use `switch`-`case` or `if` is a matter of taste. An `if`-statement will not get more "bulky" than the `switch`-`case`:

```
   if( uword1 == 65 ||
       uword1 == 69 ||
       uword1 == 73 ||
       uword1 == 76 ||
       uword1 == 78 ||
       uword1 == 79 ||
       uword1 == 82 ||
       uword1 == 83 ||
       uword1 == 84 ||
       uword1 == 85
   )
   {
       total1++;
       printf("%i", total1);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

For switch-case and if-statement both, the number of lines of code will be almost equal.

Here's how you do it in switch case:

```
switch(uword1)
    {
        case 65:
        case 69:
        case 73:
        case 76:
        case 78:
        case 79:
        case 82:
        case 83:
        case 84:
        case 85:
        total1++;
        printf("%i", total1);
        break;
        
        default:
        break;
    }
```

Here's the same code in if-statement:

```
if(
        (uword1==65) ||
        (uword1==69) ||
        (uword1==73) ||
        (uword1==76) ||
        (uword1==78) ||
        (uword1==79) ||
        (uword1==82) ||
        (uword1==83) ||
        (uword1==84) ||
        (uword1==85)
        )
    {
        total1++;
        printf("%i", total1);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This answer appears to have been covered by previous existing answers.